# HTTP Caching - Asset not serving from browser cache after setting Cache-Control Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, browser-cache, cache-control

Initial Request[image: Initial Request]
Second Request[image: Second Request]
I am using a node module(express-cache-ctrl) to enable caching on a a proxy .

```
app.use(cache.public(3600));
```

My static assets have a Cache-control header on them  with max-age . I am unable to figure out why they reload on a refresh and not served from browser-cache .

Edit : `

```
var onProxyRes = function(proxyRes, req, res) {
    if ( proxyRes.headers["content-type"] == "text/css" || 
    proxyRes.headers["content-type"] == "application/javascript") {
    proxyRes.headers["Cache-Control"] = "public, max-age=86400";
  }
```

//add something here to modify proxy response
};`
Tried manually adding caching header on proxy response  also doesn't cache assets

Comment: It seems you are using Chrome DevTool's Network panel. By default, the checkbox before "Disable cache" is checked. Have you de-select it?

Comment: @shaochuancs Disable cache has not been selected

Comment: It's weird. If cache is not disabled by DevTool, there is nothing wrong according to your screenshot.

Comment: @shaochuancs Btw i am setting my headers at the proxy level  . i don't think that should be a problem but  i am not sure now

Comment: Maybe you can set `Cache-Control` header at the original server and try again?

Comment: @shaochuancs The server(shiny-server) currently has no provision to set custom headers . It does; but that's part of the PRO distribution . And we are trying to move away from the PRO distro . http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#set-custom-headers

Comment: Let's discuss in the chat room.

Answer (score 2):

Found this in a Chrome forum  , while running a https server if you have any kind of SSL error then in that case browser prevents caching over HTTPS
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649. Works for me now